(Perutrbation theory) Linearizing a non-linear PDE to higher orders
I am currently trying to solve a non-linear PDE of the form:
$$\nabla^2 \alpha(x,y) = f(\alpha,x)+\lambda g(\alpha,x,y)$$
Here $\lambda$ is a small parameter, and I have a solution, $\alpha_0(x)$, for the case when it is zero, so naturally I tried some perturbation theory:
$$ \alpha(x,y) = \alpha_0(x)+\lambda\bar{\alpha}(x,y)$$
We can do the usual thing and Taylor expand around this solution to come up with a linearized differential equation for $\bar{\alpha}$. I will not go into all the details, but state we make substitutions like:
$$f(\alpha,x) = f(\alpha_0,x)+ \lambda \bar{\alpha}(x,y) \partial_\alpha f(x,\alpha)|_{\alpha_0}\equiv f(\alpha_0,x)+ \lambda \bar{\alpha}(x,y)f'(t)$$
Now for the actual question: If I want to expand in higher orders of $\lambda$, how should I do this? I know the first and most obvious choice should be something like:
$$ \alpha(x,y) = \sum_n \lambda^n \alpha_n(x,y)$$
but this will be cumbersome due to the form of $f(x,\alpha)$ (it is a product of trig functions). Here is an alternatives I want to try out.
Is there anything wrong with keeping more terms in the Taylor series instead? It is no longer a linear equation, but I can still probably solve the PDE with some tricks.
I could probably just use trig identities on the above intuitive expansion, separating out the lowest order $\lambda$ and expanding say $\sin(\lambda^n\alpha+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{n+1}))$ over and over but derivatives are less error prone for me... Not sure what issues I could run into doing this, so some advice would be nice!

For the series theory to work (or perturbation theory in general), the idea is that after certain terms the infinite part of the power series of $\lambda$ should be "tamable", e.g., the overall impact on the approximation to the solution is small in a norm you chose.
